# How to calculate angle within a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

Given this situation where the circle is cut by the rectangle. How do you calculate the angle **α**

[image: angle in a circle cut by rectangle]

Comment: $\sin(\alpha)=\frac dr$

Comment: @Bubububu and how do you get only α ?

Comment: @Ayoub You can use a calculator to find out the answer, it is hard to find the accurate value because the answer is transcental, which means it cannot be reprsented by sums of irrational number.

Comment: @Ayoub: use inverse trigonometry α=arcsin(d/r)

Comment: Why does my question gets negative points? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Ayoub Generally, downvotes arise from an apparent lack of work shown by the OP. You didn't show us what you tried, which is not appreciated on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a right triangle, $\sin$ is geometrically defined as the quotient of the length of the opposite side of the angle by the length of the hypotenuse.

Here, it is not clear that the side of length $d=80$ is perpendicular to the side marked as $r=130$. If it is the case, you can easily deduce that the height of the triangle is equal to $d=80$.

Let $\vert XY\vert$ denote the length of a line segment determined by some points $X$ and $Y$.

If the height of the triangle $\triangle ABC$ is $CH$, we have:

$$\sin\alpha=\frac{\vert CH\vert}{\vert AC\vert}$$

by the geometric definition of $\sin$ since the triangle $\triangle AHC$ is a right triangle in $H$ and $AC$ is its hypotenuse.

How can you determine $\vert AC\vert$? Just observe that $AC$ is a radius of the circle, hence $\vert AC\vert = 130$.

Hence, you get:

$$\sin \alpha =\frac{\vert CH\vert}{\vert AC\vert}=\frac{80}{130}=\frac{8}{13}$$

As it is not a particular value, you need the help of a calculator.

$$\alpha = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{8}{13}\right)\approx 0.662873824 \text{ rad}$$

which is about $38^{\circ}$.

**However**, be aware that the $\sin^{-1}$ functionality has to be used precautiously, but as JeanMarie put it in the comment section, it is too elaborate for your level.

[image: Angle]

Comment: Pardon me, but I think that your answer is too elaborate (not for the figure, which is very nice, but for example at the end when you say that arccos may be better that arcsin, etc...) for Ayoub that should learn first to recognize, in the first quadrant, that his exercice deals with the sine of angle $\alpha$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I totally agree with you, I shall hide this. However, I see too much students using arcsine without any precaution; the possible negative return of arcsine often misleads them.